# How to revive my olive tree :(?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, dryness, olive

I bought a 2m olive tree (see first picture) and got someone to repot and prune her. Unfortunately I think he didn’t do too great a job (second picture). Her leaves have lost their color and are brown, dry and curling, although they don’t fall off unless touched. I scraped a bit of the bark and it looks green so I think it’s still alive, I’ve put potting mix booster into the soil and fertilizer for fruit and trees.

Not sure what’s wrong with her and what to do…

Comment: The pictures aren't here.  Could you please try again.

Comment: We do need the photo, but can you also edit your question to say where you are in the world, how long you've had the plant, and whether your olive is outdoors or inside please